# JS Cookie for multiple paths

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am running into a silly issue but can't seem to find a solution.

Once a user has been logged in on my web app, I create a cookie with a JWT token so I can send it to my backend on every requests to validate the token/cookie.

```js
if (idToken) {
    document.cookie = "token=" + idToken;
    window.location.assign('/dashboard');
}
```

This is working great for all pages that do not page sub routes, example: ("/dashboard", "/help", "/etc").

**The problem:**

Now I have a sub route which is: [www.domain.com/abc/xyz](http://www.domain.com/abc/xyz)

When the request goes to that route /abc/xyz, I see two cookies being created in the browser, one on / (root path) and another one on /abc path. This is causing my trouble because my backend retrieves the requests.cookie for the current path which is /abc and eventually I get an invalid cookie.

How can I handle this properly? I tried to set a "global" cookie with root path but it did not seem to work for me:

```
document.cookie = "token=" + idToken + ";path=/";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#define_where_cookies_are_sent), specifying a path of `path=/` will indeed match all subdirectories. Your proposed solution should therefore work, and it's likely that you just need to clean your cookies for a to make sure the previous cookie does not interfere.

According to the [standard](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6265#section-5.4):

> Cookies with longer paths are listed before cookies with
> shorter paths.

If your old cookie on `/abc` does still exist, it will take precedence over your new correct one.

### Escaping (on a sidenote)

Depending on where your `idToken` comes from, it might be a good idea to escape it before setting a cookie. If your token for some reason includes a `;`, then this won't break your website.

```
document.cookie = "token=" + encodeURIComponent(idToken) + ";path=/";
```

Comment: Thanks, it was indeed a left over cookie on /abc from a previous session.